# Gitosis - I still have ssh access when I shouldn't

Tags: git, gitosis

I installed Gitosis but don't have it setup correctly. I am still able to ssh in with git user, when the docs say you're not supposed to be able to. You're only supposed run git commands which connect to the git server. Any ideas what I may have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file in Gitosis' home directory. It should only contain keys with a forced `command` to `gitosis-serve`.

Also make sure that login for the Gitosis user is only possible with SSH keys but not with a simple password.